# Break in MSVC2015 SFINAE code to match static member function signature

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, static-methods, sfinae

I've encountered an error that appears to be specific to MSVC2015, and I'm very curious exactly *why* it seems to fail. I've also filed this as a bug report against VS 2015, but I thought it'd be interesting to learn more. It's worth noting that this works perfectly in every other compiler I've tried, including MSVC2013 and MSVC2017.

The purpose is fairly straightforward - I'm checking if a type T has a static member function called New that takes some set of arguments (important for disambiguating in case there are multiple overloads)

A relatively minimal reproduction:

```
namespace {
  class MyPrivateCtorStringClass :
    public CoreObject
  {
    MyPrivateCtorStringClass(void) :
      istr("default_string")
    {}
    MyPrivateCtorStringClass(const char* istr) :
      istr(istr)
    {}

  public:
    const char* istr;

    static MyPrivateCtorStringClass* New(const char* str) {
      return new MyPrivateCtorStringClass{ str };
    }
  };
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct deducer
{
  template<class U>
  static std::true_type select(decltype(U::New((Args&&)*(Args*)nullptr...))*);

  template<class U>
  static std::false_type select(...);

  static const bool value = decltype(select<T>(nullptr))::value;
};

static_assert(
  deducer<MyPrivateCtorStringClass, decltype("")>::value,
  "PrivateString Static New was not detected"
);
```

Comment: What error are you getting, and where do you get it?

Comment: There is `std::declval<T>` to avoid those ugly `cast`.

Comment: `std::is_detected` should interest you.

Comment: Use `constexpr` instead of `const` for compile time constants and I'm pretty sure `decltype("")` evaluates to `const char[]`

Comment: Error for gcc/clang BTW: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/003b43cd1dd04575)